# XML parsing error in php

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

When I use the below code and parse the xml locally it works fine but when upload the same script at the server it shows error. the code is

Note: I retrieved the `$lng` and `$lat` from the query string and it works fine locally.

```
$lng=$_GET['lng'];
$lat=$_GET['lat'];
$conn=new LoginSystem();
$conn->connect();
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$query="select catch_id,catch_details,image from mycatch where longitude='$lng' AND latitude='$lat'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}
header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $node = $dom->createElement("mycatch");
  $node = $dom->appendChild($node);

  foreach ($row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {
       $child = $dom->createElement($fieldname);
       $child = $node->appendChild($child);
       $value = $dom->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
       $value = $child->appendChild($value);
  }
}

$conn->disconnect();
$xml_string = $dom->saveXML();
echo $xml_string;
```

On the server I get this error. And the document is also empty.....

> This page contains the following errors:
>   error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
>   Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to define a root element for the XML document.

At the moment you seem to have

```
<mycatch>
 <catch_id>1</catch_id>
 <catch_details>details</catch_details>
 <image>image</image>
</mycatch>
<mycatch>
 <catch_id>2</catch_id>
 <catch_details>details</catch_details>
 <image>image</image>
</mycatch>
...
```

But you don't have a root element such as:

```
<catches>
    <mycatch>
     <catch_id>1</catch_id>
     <catch_details>details</catch_details>
     <image>image</image>
    </mycatch>
    <mycatch>
     <catch_id>2</catch_id>
     <catch_details>details</catch_details>
     <image>image</image>
    </mycatch>
</catches>
```

Comment: does't work on server i checked it locally it works but on server the document remains empty

Comment: So have you verified that the SQL query works on the server and returns some valid records?